# AngularJS string interpolation not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, I can't seem to get string interpolation ({{}}) to work in my angularJS setup. I'm running with the MEAN stack I downloaded from [here](http://www.mean.io/#!/) about a month ago and trying to replicate the [angular-ui accordion example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) in my environment. In my template I have this:

```
<accordion close-others="true">

    <accordion-group is-open="true" class="no-padding" ng-repeat="optSet in chartOptions">
        <accordion-heading>{{optSet.name || 'broken...'}}</accordion-heading>
        <div ng-include src="'option-content'" ng-init="options = optSet.data"></div>

    </accordion-group>

</accordion>
```

then I have this in my controller:

```
$scope.chartOptions = [
    { 'name': 'Axis', 'data': chartAxisOptions }
];
```

but all I ever get is 'broken...' even though there's clearly a name attribute there as well. It's weird because it definitely renders based on the data I give it, but the name is not working at all. I have also tried adding it to the header attribute of the `<accordion-group>`, and making it check `optSet['name']` as well -- the latter gives me undefined, in fact.

Comment: Why do you have a controller if you're making a directive? do you hvae a sscce? http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I'm not making a directive, I'm using the one in [the example that I linked above](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion). I do not have a SSCCE, but I fear even if I did it would work correctly. Something in my environment obviously isn't correct but I'm not knowledgeable enough to troubleshoot further.

Comment: I don't know what you need help with. Does the console give you any errors?
http://plnkr.co/edit/GqBTrOMarAN9KYPtPcA8?p=preview

Comment: I do not get any console errors. I need help with figuring out why string interpolation doesn't work for me, but all the demos I see, it works just fine. I was hoping there was some "gotcha" or some obvious solution. Maybe there's a way I can set up a demo directly from my machine?

Comment: What if you change the angular version?

Comment: I upgraded to the same version being used in the angular-ui-bootstrap and was still having problems. It was apparently something in the MEAN stack that was causing problems.. I had to have someone review the whole project and gut it and I'm still in the process of figuring out exactly why it wasn't working. I'll post an answer when I know more... thanks for your help thus far though @Roger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [MEAN stack](http://mean.io) has some really weird setup issues. There was an issue with the Express twig templates, and angular interpolation. After making everything use angular, string interpolation worked again.